# How to see results of multiple SQL queries in Databricks?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have a cell with multiple SQL queries like `MERGE`, `SELECT` etc. When I run the notebook through a workflow TASK I can see the output of the last run SQL query for a particular cell only. How to see output for each queries?

Comment: @SaiVamsi there is no code question here. It's a product related "how-to" question.

Comment: Have had this problem as well...One option that we follow is to make the cell a python cell, enclose the queries in a variable and execute them via spark.sql() and if needed display the output. If it is manual and not within a task, you could always select it and run using a key combo that eludes me now. Applicable on runtimes 11.2 and above if I am not mistaken. Hope this helps. Please do share if you come across a different solution.

Comment: @rainingdistros spark.sql is not a viable solution now. As the codebase has grown huge. Can't waste time to wrap them with python function.